# Set border for QSpinBox when focused

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

For already existed Qt project I'd like set border for focused widgets through qss-fle. But I faced out with some unexpected result. When I change border of `QSpinBox` (and `QDoubleSpinBox`) border will change as I expect but up-button and down-button change too and look ugly.

[image]

Here is my style definition (full example available [here](https://gitlab.com/Gluttton/SOS/tree/master/35162425)):

```
QSpinBox:focus
{
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
}
```

My question is: how to change appearance of border and simultaneously preserve appearance of up-button and down-button. Solution what I am looking for shouldn't be cross platform or cross version.

My environment:
- KUbuntu 15.10 (amd64);
- Qt 5.4 (x64).

**Update**:

Here is one more example with another style:

```
QSpinBox
{
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color : red;
}

QSpinBox:hover
{
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: blue;
}
```

The widget looks like this:

[image]

Comment: i guess you have already tried to set a style for your up-arrow and down-arrow ? If not there is qss examples there http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qspinbox

Comment: Your problem is maybe due to the propagation of your "focus" style to the whole widget including arrows, in particular the border-with property.. which could cause this kind of unexpected behavior

Comment: @floppy12, I have not try. It is difficult for me to reproduce appearance of buttons.

Comment: You should not reproduce it entirely ; i meant you should precise a style even a default one to prevents you "focus" style to override it - take an example from the link below and try it

Comment: @floppy12, `precise a style even a default one`  I can't see how to do it. Can you provide some example? Do you mean: `QSpinBox::up-button {}`?

Comment: For what it's worth: I get a very similar behaviour on Qt5.4 on Windows when setting your stylesheet to a spinbox -- the buttons look ugly. Indeed it seems that once you do a any stylesheet change to the spinbox, you have to go all the way and specify the rest via stylesheet, too (as floppy12 suggested). But really: Are we (i.e. the OP) supposed to provide our own handmade `up_arrow.png` etc. to make a simple stylechange work? How messed up is that? I agree with Glutton that this would be difficult!

Comment: When you change a border - then native platform style is removed. There is only one way to prevent such fails: is to use sone non-native styles. For example: `QApplication::setStyle( QStyleFactory::create( "Fusion" ) );`

Comment: @Saz , When I add the following line, appearance of the widget will remain the same as screenshot.

Comment: Please take a look at this post: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/43489-QSpinBox-setting-buttons-with-using-stylesheets

Answer (score 4):

When you apply a style sheet to the `QSpinBox`, this widget is completely painted using the `QStyleSheetStyle` (this class is not part of the public API).

So you have to either style your spin box completely, including the up/down buttons or not to use the style sheet at all.

That up/down buttons are not separated widgets, so you can't apply a different style to them.

So I suggest to subclass the `QSpinBox` and reimplement the `paintEvent()` method. In your `paintEvent()` method you will just call it's default implementation and than you will draw a rectangle around.

Comment: exactly what i suggested... +1

Answer (score 2):

try to edit your qss file with another random style to see if it's consistent.

```
QSpinBox
{
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color : red;
}

QSpinBox:hover
{
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: blue;
}
```

Edit :

I see that your arrows are still in bad form so I would suggest you two things :

- style also your up-down arrows with background image property or so (take a screen shot of the desired arrows..or so)
- forger to style this part via stylesheet and override the  "QPaintEvent onFocus handler" by code. Setting the border as green wouldn't be so painful

Comment: Edited with suggestion

Comment: First case is very bad for me. Second case more or less acceptable, but anyway this is not a solution.